# CMake rewrite include path

Tags: c++, cmake

Is there a way to rewrite the path of a included dir?

When the includes are placed in `./urg_library-1.2.5/include/cpp`, is there a way to satisfy the required include `#include "urg_cpp/Urg_driver.h"`?

I'm currently using `include_directories("./urg_library-1.2.5/include/cpp")` only capable of using `#include "Urg_driver.h"` giving me

```
urg/Connection_information.h:12:10: fatal error: urg_cpp/Urg_driver.h: File or 
dir not found
   12 | #include "urg_cpp/Urg_driver.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: File with relative location `urg_cpp/Urg_driver.h` exists nowhere on your machine, so it cannot be found by the compiler in any case. CMake is not a magic tool which changes behavior of the compiler.